# From Json [{"Keys": "Values"}], how to fetch VALUES from .json file

Tags: python, arrays, json, object

```
[
    {
        "Key": "VAlUE"  
    },
    {
        "Key": "VAlUE"
    }
]
```

Question:- returns Values as ouptut not key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these keys and values are stored in a .json file with the exact format you specified, utilizing the json module like so will produce your required results:

```
import json
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for item in data:
        for _,value in item.items():
            print(value)
```

The code first opens a specified json file for reading, then iterates over each key/value pair, printing each value as it traverses the file.